# Why is that Jquery for datepicker is not closing onclick, outside of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I use datepicker Jquery to select date and below is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"   href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
        jQuery("#datepicker").blur(function(e) { 
            jQuery(this).datepicker("hide");  
        });
    });
</script>
```

It works when I use `.blur` function. But, I am not able to change the month. When I change the month, it hides. How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: By default, clicking outside should hide it. So instead, try to check why it isn't. Provide MCVE replicating your issue

Comment: You can also handle document on click check if datepicker window is visible  and if target isn't datepicker window or isn't child of it; than close it.

Comment: @Sojtin please give me a snippet of code.

Comment: works fine [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/x0KV3pvOgZa22svimyzN?p=preview) using your code. Have been around jQuery UI datepicker for many years since they rolled out jQueryUI and never heard of issue like this. Something else is wrong, not the code shown

Comment: @Sojtin that functionality is built in and works fine

Comment: any errors in dev tools console?

Comment: Datepicker is closed if not any decendant or element itself fire `mousedown` event bound at `document` level. Maybe you are just stoping this event to bubble to `document` level...

Comment: when i include latest min jquery in header then its not work

Comment: @user5876330 See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then edit your question... If you test your posted code, without the blur event, then you'll see it works, so... And btw you should read about the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)